# How to print a list of tuples in this specific way? python

Tags: python, list, printing, tuples

For example, i have this list of tuples:

```
a=[(6, '♥'), (10, '♣'), (10, '♦')]
```

and the print i would want would be like this:

```
My elements in a are 6 of ♥, 10 of ♣ and 10 of ♦.
```

printing like this is easy but the thing is my list is going to vary, it may have three tuples like this one or 5, so i wanna know what i have to do to make the printing more fluid. thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Also what do you want the output to look like when ‘a’ has only one element?

Comment: This is the minimun is gonna have, is going to vary between 3 and 5

Comment: Ok, so what went wrong with the code you have tried?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
a=[(6, '♥'), (10, '♣'), (10, '♦')]

def pp_list(input_list):
    output_string = ""
    for idx, x in enumerate(input_list):
        if idx != len(input_list) -1:
            output_string += " of ".join((str(x[0]), x[1])) + ", "
        else:
            output_string += "and " + " of ".join((str(x[0]), x[1])) + "."
    return "My elements in a are: {}".format(output_string)

print(pp_list(a))
```

Provides me with the following output:

```
My elements in a are: 6 of ♥, 10 of ♣, and 10 of ♦.
```

This should work regardless of how big your input list is (not the cleanest of code but should do exactly what you want)

Comment: thanks a lot this was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: you are more than welcome :)

Comment: Some tweaks that will help readability: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1953335

Comment: Why not use proper string formatting, instead of messing around with `join()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Make one function that takes a tuple and turns it into a string,

```py
def card_tuple_to_string(tup):
    rank, suit = tup
    return f"{rank} of {suit}"
```

Then another that takes a list of strings and formats correctly.

```py
def format_list_of_cards(cards):
    *init, last = cards
    if init:
        init.append('and ')
    return f"My elements are {', '.join(init)}{last}"
```

Then chain them together.

```py
a=[(6, '♥'), (10, '♣'), (10, '♦')]

stringified_a = [card_tuple_to_string(tup) for tup in a]
result = format_list_of_cards(stringified_a)
```

---

That said, it's probably ideal to abstract this all away into a `Card` object that just knows what to do.

```py
class Card(object):
    SUITS = {'♥', '♣', '♦', '♠'}

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        if suit not in self.SUITS:
            raise ValueError("Card: Invalid suit " + suit)
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.rank} of {self.suit}"

    @staticmethod
    def format_hand(hand):
        *init, last = hand
        if init:
            init.append('and ')
        return f"{', '.join(init)}{last}"
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer ah you're right. Sorry, been spending my time in Groovy lately where the syntax is reversed. Fixed.

Comment: @MarkMeyer this new code, while kind of hacky, also handles single-element lists. It does _not_ handle empty lists, which would have to be special-cased.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the string representation of a card in a class rather than a tuple,

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, num, suit):
        self.num = num
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return '{num} of {suit}'.format(num=self.num, suit=self.suit)
```

and then the printing can be done as,

```
cards=[Card(6, '♥'), Card(10, '♣'), Card(10, '♦')]
print('My elements are ' + ', and'.join(', '.join([str(card) for card in cards]).rsplit(',', maxsplit=1)))
```

Alternatively, if you still want tuples, you can just make a function which takes a tuple and returns the string

```
def tup_to_str(tup):
    return '{} of {}'.format(*tup)
```

and then print using this function

```
'My elements are ' + ', and'.join(', '.join([tup_to_str(card) for card in a]).rsplit(',', maxsplit=1))
```

Comment: Can you give some example outputs from your code?

Comment: My elements are 6 of ♥, 10 of ♣ and 10 of ♦,                                                        My elements are 6 of ♥, 10 of ♣, 10 of ♦ and A of  ♣                                                        My elements are 6 of ♥, 10 of ♣, 10 of ♦, A of  ♣ and 7 of ♣                                              somethin like this

Answer (score 0):

You can build a list of formatted strings for each card and then join this list with the appropriate separator depending on how many there are.

```
a=[(6, '♥'), (10, '♣'), (10, '♦')]

asStrings      = [f"{n} of {s}" for n,s in a]    # convert to list of cards expressed as strings
asStrings[-2:] = [" and ".join(asStrings[-2:])]  # connect last two with an "and" 
if not a        : print("The list is empty")
elif len(a)==1  : print("The only element in the list is " + asStrings[0])
else            : print("The elements in the list are " + ", ".join(asStrings)) # connect elements with a comma
```

output:

```
The elements in the list are 6 of ♥, 10 of ♣ and 10 of ♦
```